# MySQL- Compare Customer IDs from two tables to determine who made no purchases

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have two tables in SQL, one with information on customers and orders placed by them (columns include customerid, contactname, orderid, quantity, to name a few).  My second table is simply a list of all customer ids, and my task is to determine which customerID didn't make a purchase.  Some of the customer ids made multiple purchases, so I am unsure of how to use SELECT DISTINCT to compare the two tables.

Comment: could you add some sample data?

Comment: CustomerID| CompanyName|ContactName|ContactTitle| Address|City|Region|PostalCode|Country| Phone|Fax|OrderID| OrderDate|RequiredDate| ShippedDate| EmployeeID|Freight($) |ProductID |UnitPrice($) |Quantity |Discount(%)                                                                       
VINET|Vins et alcools Chevalier|Paul Henriot| Accounting Manager| 59 rue de l'Abbaye| Reims| NULL|51100|France|26.47.15.10|26.47.15.11|10248| 2016-07-04| 2016-08-01| 2016-07-16|5|32.38|11| 14.00| 12| 0

Comment: Sorry for the harsh formatting.  That is all an example of the header row and one row of data.

Comment: Hi better if you could add two tables along with the question.
So anybody will be able to understand the question properly and could give you a pin pointed answer. Can`t determine how to identify a purchase without knowing more info

Answer (score 1):

join the second table and filter the results

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.customerid, t1.contactname
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
    WHERE t1.customerid = t2.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t2.customerid
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.customerid = t2.customerid);
```